# UIDatePicker components not scrolling properly and sometimes moves outside of the view

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker components not scrolling properly and sometimes moves outside of the view.

Tried with adding date picker programatically as well as using storyboards.

I am assigning date picker as textField's input view. And textField is in table view cell. 
**Code**

```
func assignDatePickerTo(textField: UITextField) { 
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker() 
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date 
    let currentDate = Date() 
    datePicker.minimumDate = currentDate      
    datePicker.setDate(currentDate, animated: false) 
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white     
     datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.neededFromDateChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged) 

    textField.inputView = datePicker 
}
```

**UI Screenshot below**

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working properly.

Comment: Can you try this same by taking new datePicker after deleting this one.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy  Please see the attached screenshot the year component is showing in the middle and starts with 1 even if I set minimum date

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of how you instantiated it?

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy Tried it. Actually i'm assigning the the date picker as textfield's input view

Comment: Mail me your project

Comment: Here is code:
func assignDatePickerTo(textField: UITextField) {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        let currentDate = Date()
        datePicker.minimumDate = currentDate
        datePicker.setDate(currentDate, animated: false)
        formatAndShowDate(date: currentDate, textField: textField)
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(self.neededFromDateChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        textField.inputView = datePicker
    }

Comment: You should edit the question, adding that code to it. Comments can be easily deleted.

Comment: @CPHPython Edited question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to some other third party library in which they have written the category on scrollView to updateContentSize when scrollView updates constraints which is getting called when I scroll datePicker.